# Free Sprite Stacking Program for Linux

Tags: 3d, pixel-graphics

I have found spritestack.io app, but I can't afford it. Is there any good Free Alternatives to it. That would be so nice.

Free means either the App (binary file) be free or the app is Open Source or Both.

If the app has some similarities with spritestack.io, that would be even more perfect.

I would like to run the app in Linux and without Wine.

Thank You.

Or even there's no app, is there a way that a different app could do it or multiple number of apps could do it, any thing is OK for me.

Edit: All I specifically want to do some modelling which I could use in various 3D app (especially in godot), if its not possible then I will just stick with modelling and export as a 2d image (the image contains what the camera sees) and just have it. Or both is good for me. :)

Comment: Please detail what **you** want the program to do _rather than something like this site_ as it will allow people to point you to the most appropriate tool(s).

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to generate sprite sheets then you can use the [Image Magick](https://imagemagick.org/) [montage](https://imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) command as can be seen in [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37198/sprite-sheet-generator/37211#37211) on gaming.

Image Magick is:

- Free, gratis & Open Source
- Available on most platforms
- Command line driven (great for scripts)
- Very powerful